# How to save and restore area in GDI+

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

How to save a rectangular area of pixels (I mean their colors) on a GDI+ drawing and then redraw this area with the saved data? I suppose that the class Bitmap may be helpful, but have no idea with which methods to do the task.

I.e. the main task is to get and set the color of a pixel with coordinates x, y on a form. Method Control.DrawToBitmap allows only to save the whole image of the form into a bitmap, while I need to save/redraw only a small area. Any suggestions?

Comment: The second parameter to Control.DrawToBitmap is the size of the area you wish to copy. You can make it as small as you want.

Comment: I have tested the method Form.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, Rectangle) and found that when you pass the Rectangle (x, y, width, height) it copies top left contents of the form of specified width and height to the x, y position in the Bitmap! So you can only copy some top left piece of your form to the bitmap. And I need to copy arbitrary rectangle of the form. Such behaviour of the method DrawToBitmap looks quite strange. Please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong and if possible provide a piece of code. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should try to tell us a little more what you need to do? When you have control over all code yourself, there is seldom any need to use DrawToBitmap.

Comment: I am doing animation in GDI+. I'm drawing some mark in the drawing area, then I need to delete that mark and restore the image that was previously under it.

Comment: Well, you should never ever rely on anything on the form. Build all your graphics on Bitmap objects and paint them to screen as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I currently use the BufferedGraphics class to draw the image in a buffer and then render it with Render() method to the screen.